# set SqlConnection string properly

Tags: c#

Im encountering a problem when setting sqlconnection.
this is my `Web.Config` file :

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SimpleDB"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\FluksikartoN\Documents\SimpleDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
         providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

So basically i want to add row "Hello" to sql table named "book" which has only one string column caled "Name" on button click , but i get error : "`[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]`" and i dont see anything wrong in sqlconnection set up.

`aspx.cs` file :

```
using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Web.Services;

    namespace ProjectWWW
    {
        public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]     
            public static string InsertData(string ID){
                string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:/Users/FluksikartoN/Documents/SimpleDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Book (Name) values(@Name)", con))
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ID);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                            return "True";
                        }
                    }
        }




        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InsertData("hELLO");
        }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you putting a connection string in web.config and then not using it?  You're hardcoding the same connection string in code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Web.Config connection string

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimpleDB"].ToString();
```

there is no need of specifying connection string on page when you have specified it in Web.Config

Comment: you should include `System.Configuration` namespace, like this `using System.Configuration`

Comment: add `.ToString()` in the end like this `string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimpleDB"].ToString();` , updated the ans with `.ToString()`

Answer (score 5):

You've changed your backslashes to forward slashes.  Change them back and use `@` to not treat them as escape characters:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\FluksikartoN\Documents\SimpleDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

or just pull it from `app.config` since you put it there as well:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SimpleDB"];
```

Comment: holy jesus thanks this bothered me 3 days in a row im new and i hate when this kind of missunderstandings fail me

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like this in your .cs file

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.CofigurationManager.ConnectionString["SqlConn"].ConnectionString.ToString());
```

I hope this will work for you.